# Got "EAGAIN" error when sending request with "request module" (node.js module)

Tags: node.js, request, httprequest

I have the same code for my Windows and Linux. It works on Windows but failed with my Linux.

Code:

```
  request({url:target_url}, // ANY URL WILL FAIL
    function (err, response, body) {
      console.log(err);
```

Out put error for this in my console:

```
{ [Error: connect EAGAIN] code: 'EAGAIN', errno: 'EAGAIN', syscall: 'connect' }
```

I guess this is not an issue with the request module but i don't know where to get help. Thanks for any kind of tips!

Comment: which version of node are you using and did you downloaded the binary or build it from source ?

Comment: @user568109 Thanks for your reply, the version I use is v0.10.10 - I install node via apt-get